# What is ACT! in Salesforce

Tags: data-loader, data-import-wizard, data-import

What is ACT! in Salesforce
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=exporting_from_act.htm&type=5 article talks about this and I see ACT! file on data import wizard and in one trailhead link but I could not find any solid documentation link for ACT!
From https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000gzZqAAI I guess that ACT! file is a data file with notes and attachment file. But if it is a file then why the first link writes "Launch ACT!" which tells that it may be a program. 
So what is ACT! file exactly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ACT! is another CRM system (so a competitor to Salesforce) see [the wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Act!_CRM).

The documentation you've linked says that it's possible to export contact data from ACT! (as some file using a text-delimited format) and import it into Salesforce, that's all.